# Shuffling a deck of $n$ cards probability

Tags: probability

We have a deck of $n$ cards. We take cards from the deck one by one, and we flip the card. If the card goes side up, we put it at the end of the deck and if the card falls side down, we leave it where it is.

The probability of the flip is $1/2$ for side up or side down.

What is the probability that after we go through $n$ cards like this, that we get the same order of cards?

My try:

1.)

i)If we flip them all side down, it stays the same.

ii)If we flip the last $m$ cards side up, it stays the same because they are at the end of the deck anyway. Here $m$ can be equal to $n$ or $n-1,...,1$

So every card has $1/2$ that it either goes to the end of the deck or it doesn't. So the sample space would be: $2^n$

My solution: We get $\frac{(n+1)}{2^n}$, since there are only $n+1$ favourable outcomes.

2.)
What would we do if the probability of flipping the card side up would be $p$?

Then I suppose we would have: $ \sum_{k=0}^n (p^{k} \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}) $  To get the cards at the end of the deck and here we also have the probability that they are all face down in the sum (for $k = 0$)

3.) What would we do if the probability is $p$ of going side up, but there is also a probability $c$ that we skip a card (so that we don't even look at it or flip it) and there is also a probability $d$ that we put the card into the thrash (so out of the deck).

So for 3.) I tried:

$1 - (p + c + d)= P(\text{flip side down})$

And here I see that $c$ is actually the probability of the same event as to flip it side down, since the card stays in the same position.
So we can say $P(\text{stays in the same position}) = 1- (p+d)$.

So $P(\text{all same position after first shuffle}) = (1- (p+d))^n + \sum_{k = 1}^n (1-(p+d))^{n-k}$

Are 1.), 2.) and 3.) correct ?

4.) What would we do if $d$ and $c$ would be $c + d = 1$ and $P(\text{flip side down}) = 1-p$, so in other words $c$ would be the conditional probability to flip the card, $P(p|c) = ?$ and $P(1-p|c) = ?$